# Why am I not able to activate virtual environment in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run `venv\Scripts\activate` in cmd, I am able to use venv but in VS Code I can not use venv and I get this error:

```
PS F:\Python\Python-Inoventaa\Python Flask\FlaskProject\FlaskBlogProject> venv\Scripts\activate
venv\Scripts\activate : 
File F:\Python\Python-Inoventaa\Python Flask\FlaskProject\FlaskBlogProject\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on 
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ venv\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Does the project you currently open in VSCode have the virtual environment "venv"? Could you provide us with more details about how you run this command?

Answer (score 12):

Try this: On the terminal of vs-code at the right side selected cmd instead of power shell.

see the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxRPS.png

Answer (score 3):

You can use this script on VS Code's terminal:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
```

for more detail you can visit official VS Code website about Python programming at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by adding this configuration to your settings.json file suggested from this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2559#issuecomment-478381840)

By going to your settings.json (on windows):

`%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`

or

`C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

and adding this line in the configuration (use comma at the end if there are more config lines):

```
{
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
}
```

and it should be solved once you open another Terminal.

Comment: This is what I was after, except the path is now:`"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows":{"PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
        }}

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the previous answer, it is due to execution policy of PowerShell terminal in VSCode.

To bypass the execution policy while using VSCode, you may add a modified PowerShell profile and set it as default profile in the JSON settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell venv": { 
        "source": "PowerShell", 
        "icon": "terminal-powershell", 
        "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"] }},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell venv",
```

or you may also choose to modify the default PowerShell, mentioned by @John:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": { 
        "source": "PowerShell", 
        "icon": "terminal-powershell", 
        "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"] }},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
```

Comment: This one worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: On the terminal of vs-code at the right side selected cmd instead of power shell.

Comment: This is a verbatim copy of @straight-coding 's answer

Answer (score 0):

Changing to cmd instead of powershell will definitely work in vs code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63850361/18145256).